# make my current link active

Tags: php, css, url

Well lets try to explain am sorry about my english.

I have some xml files where I get the url from with some php scripts

everything goes right the only prob is i want to change the li BGcolor of the selected link like in css :active or giving only that link   eg a class="current"

this below make dynamically the urls to the data

```
echo "<ul><li ><a  href='?xml1=".$xmlGet."&link=".$link." '>".$slide->title."</a></li></ul><br/>";
```

with the above i get a list of links not only one like below as urls

```
http://localhost/html5/playerEnd/hoofdstuks.php?xml1=chapter_3733&link=1
http://localhost/html5/playerEnd/hoofdstuks.php?xml1=chapter_3733&link=2
http://localhost/html5/playerEnd/hoofdstuks.php?xml1=chapter_3733&link=3
etc etc
```

and it display as menu like this

link 1
link 2
link 3
link 4
etc etc

each link load a different data to my page when clicked so i want the one clicked to be active like an other color or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_GET['link']` to find out which link has been clicked.  Then add a class to the link which corresponds to this.  You'll have to define the `active` class.

```
$linkID = $_GET['link'];

echo "<ul><li ><a  href='?xml1=".$xmlGet."&link=".$link." '";

if ($linkID == $link) { echo " class=\"active\" "; }

echo ">".$slide->title."</a></li></ul><br/>";
```

And if you want the li to have the class (as asked in comments):

```
$linkID = $_GET['link'];

echo "<ul><li";

if ($linkID == $link) { echo " class=\"active\" "; }

echo "><a  href='?xml1=".$xmlGet."&link=".$link."'>".$slide->title."</a></li></ul><br/>";
```

Comment: I usually store classname (or whole attribute) to a variable and then output whole tag in a single `echo` statement. Something like `foreach ( $links as $linkID => $linkName ) { $active = $linkID == $_GET['id'] ? 'class="active"' : ''; echo "<a href='?id={$linkID}' {$active}>{$linkName}</a>"; }`, but with newlines, of course ;) This seems to be a bit more readable than echo'ing single tag in 3 lines with condition.

Comment: u make my day thnx u very very very much Bless where to give u point?? :)

Comment: and other question if i want the <li> to have the class??